# In guice is there a difference between @provides and bind()?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am wondering what the difference is between using **`@provides`** on a method and using **`bind()`** in my guice modules.

---

I usually override AbstractModule.configure() and bind all my implementations to my interfaces like this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule
{
  @Override
  protected void configure()
  {
    this.bind(myIface.class).to(myIfaceImpl.class);
    this.bind(myOtherIface.class).to(myOtherIfaceImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();
  }
  ...
}
```

However, I have noticed a pattern in the codebase I'm currently working with where implementations aren't bound explicitly they are being returned from providers like this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule
{
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  myIface iFaceProvider()
  {
    return new myIfaceImpl();
  }
  ...
}
```

---

***Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?  Are there cases that force a particular method?***

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you do

```java
bind(MyInterface.class).to(MyImplementation.class)
```

Guice creates the instance for you.  This enables certiain things like AOP.  If you do

```java
@Provides
MyInterface provideMyInterface() {
    return new MyImplementation();
}
```

then Guice didn't create the instance so AOP won't work.  Also, it requires an accessible constructor for `MyImplementation`.  Generally, this form is only used when you can't edit `MyImplementation` to make it Guice-compatible.

There's a third form:

```java
@Provides
MyInterface provideMyInterface(MyImplementation impl) {
    return impl;
}
```

which is almost totally equivalent to the `bind(...).to(...)` form.  It is commonly used in frameworks like Dagger that do not have the `bind` syntax.

Comment: How about the relationship of all this with javax.inject? Neither in your code nor the OP's we see what annotations are imported; this may have an impact if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: There should be no difference.  The only difference I'm aware of is Guice will refuse to inject into `final` fields with `@javax.inject.Inject`, but it will try with `@com.google.inject.Inject`.

Comment: @fge Also there is no `javax.inject.Provides`